# why copy statement blocks other alter statements in postgersql

Tags: database, postgresql

I have one process which executes copy statement, which loads data to 'table1' from a file. I have another process which is executing alter table statement on 'table2'. But the 2nd query gets blocked until copy statement is running. How come postgreSQL blocks the alter table statement? Checked using a query

```
SELECT blocked_locks.pid     AS blocked_pid,
         blocked_activity.usename  AS blocked_user,
         blocking_locks.pid     AS blocking_pid,
         blocking_activity.usename AS blocking_user,
         blocked_activity.query    AS blocked_statement,
         blocking_activity.query   AS current_statement_in_blocking_process
   FROM  pg_catalog.pg_locks         blocked_locks
    JOIN pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity blocked_activity  ON blocked_activity.pid = blocked_locks.pid
    JOIN pg_catalog.pg_locks         blocking_locks
        ON blocking_locks.locktype = blocked_locks.locktype
        AND blocking_locks.database IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.database
        AND blocking_locks.relation IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.relation
        AND blocking_locks.page IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.page
        AND blocking_locks.tuple IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.tuple
        AND blocking_locks.virtualxid IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.virtualxid
        AND blocking_locks.transactionid IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.transactionid
        AND blocking_locks.classid IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.classid
        AND blocking_locks.objid IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.objid
        AND blocking_locks.objsubid IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.objsubid
        AND blocking_locks.pid != blocked_locks.pid

    JOIN pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity blocking_activity ON blocking_activity.pid = blocking_locks.pid
   WHERE NOT blocked_locks.granted;
```

The output was:

```
blocked_pid,blocked_user,blocking_pid,blocking_user,blocked_statement,current_statement_in_blocking_process
4669,user91,4182,user91,ALTER TABLE "part_me***" DETACH PARTITION "part_met***11";DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "part_meta****11";
                    COPY table2_name 
                    (customer_**,**_customer_id,part_**,price,quantity,valid_from,valid_to,last_updated) 
                    FROM 
                    STDIN 
                    WITH 
                        (
                            HEADER TRUE,
                            FORMAT csv
                        )
                    "
```

Why does postgesql block alter table query?

Comment: Do you have a foreign key constraint between the two tables?

Comment: No foreign key between two tables.

Comment: Triggers on table2_name that will modify part_me***?

Comment: There are foreign key relations on the table, is that what it's blocking alter table query?